# How to make end point of a line follow a particular trajectory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, line, simulation

I want to plot a line and then make one end of a line follow a particular trajectory. My main aim is to make knee and hip joints and I want the lines out of both joints to follow a trajectory. I want to simulate my joints as shown in this image:

[image].

Here the red curve shows the trajectory of the lowest point of the second line.

How to do this?

Comment: I see two basic questions in here. 1) how to solve the inverse kinematics and determine the position of the knee joint for each position of the foot 2) how to draw the whole in an animation. Where do you struggle? Are you able to calculate and plot the positions for an standing frame?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a for loop and inside it, draw for each time step a different curve. In order to do this, you can use plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2]) where x1,y1 is your constant point and x2,y2 your variable point. Also, deactivate “hold” so that at each step, the previous line is erased. 
Good luck